# forien key in django model

Tags: django, model

I have 2 error in my code :

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cream'`

and

`ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'cream'.`

and my code contains :

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    color_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = ' ')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = '')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ''
        verbose_name_plural = ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
```

and

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES,)
    ...
    number = models.ForeignKey("Numbers", related_name="numbers", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="")
    color = models.ForeignKey("Colors", related_name='colors', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="")
    size = models.ForeignKey("Sizes", related_name='sizes', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="")
```

what is my mistake?

Comment: I recommend you lookup the keyword "cream" in your code and start from there.
Your models seem fine. Can't help you without further information.

Comment: show the code where you are creating a product. You are likely passing 'cream' instead of the integer representing cream or the object for cream colour.

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is not there so could not help you with code but somewhere you are passing color_code as a string "cream" where as your field is a Integer field so that's why you are getting this error so fix that and this will be resolved.

Comment: File "/media/mosi/Science/web_project/kourosh/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cream'